# filter pandas dataframe by inserting zeros based on another data farme index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

is there anyway to filter the first dataframe based on the index of second dataframe and generate the output dataframe? In first datafarme, we filterout the rows whose index are present in second dataframe and need to insert whole 0 zero in place of index value of second dataframe.

first dataframe

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
A   1   1   1   1
B   1   1   1   1
C   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   1   1
```

second dataframe

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
A   1   1   1   1
```

output dataframe

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
A   0   0   0   0
B   1   1   1   1
C   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have 1s in `df2`, a simple method would be a subtraction:

```
out = df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Otherwise, build a mask using reindexed `df2`:

```
out = df1.mask(df2.notna().reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns, fill_value=False), 0)
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
A   0   0   0   0
B   1   1   1   1
C   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   1   1
```